# Using the letters a, b, c, d, e, f, how many 4 letter words can we create which contain "a"? Repetition is allowed

Tags: permutations, combinations

I thought of this solution, but I think it is wrong.
First digit: 1 * 6 * 6 * 6
Second digit: 6 * 1 * 6 * 6
Third digit: ......
Fourth digit: ....
And at the end, the answer would be 216. But that contains a lot of duplicate words we don't want.

Comment: How many 4 letter words can be created in total here? How many 4 letter words can be created that do **not** contain a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

How many $4$ letter words can be created in total here?

How many $4$ letter words can be created that do **not** contain letter **a**?